# Node js server on Amazon S3 & Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a simple Node js server on Amazon AWS (S3 & Cloudfront). Here the step that I followed :

- Created my AWS account
- Created my bucket on S3
- Created my CloudFront web distribution

Everything is working well, but what would be the next step to install an Node Js server and run it ?

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

S3 is not a server, it's storage for static files.

You need to setup a EC2 and install your node server into it.

If you just want to serve a static JS lib for your clients, then you can use S3 bucket and Cloudfront.

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/webinars/